# Do While with String Statement

Tags: c

Ok.. so i have that code and i cant get the Do While statement right...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
    int nWinsPC, nWinsPlayer;
    char cChoose[1];
    do {
    system("cls");
        printf("Vamos jogar um jogo?\n");
        printf("-\n");
        printf("Escolha (p)edra, p(a)pel ou (t)esoura: ");
        getchar();
        scanf("%1[^\n]", cChoose);
    } while(cChoose != "p");
    system("pause");
}
```

That system should be that easy... the CHOOSE SCREEN stays in loop while Player doesnt type "p", but i can't get this working...

:(

thanks in advance

**EDIT**

Problem solved:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
    int nWinsPC, nWinsPlayer;
    char cChoose[2];
    do {
    system("cls");
        printf("Vamos jogar um jogo?\n");
        printf("-\n");
        printf("Escolha (p)edra, p(a)pel ou (t)esoura: ");
        scanf("%s", cChoose);
    } while ( strcmp(cChoose,"p") );
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: This is not a problem solved, but a problem created.  This code will enter an infinite loop if the input stream is closed.  You must check the return value of scanf and compare against EOF!  It would much better to use getchar() instead of scanf().  You also need to flush stdout before the scanf if you want to actually see the prompt reliably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement :

```
strcmp ( cChoose, "p" )
```

must be used which returns zero if two strings are equal.
Moreover, if you are using cChoose as a string you must use two characters as the length of cChoose because string is always terminated by a null character - '\0'. So, use :

```
char cChoose[2];
```

EDIT:

The getchar() before the scanf() takes the initial 'p', thus nothing happens first time. Whereas the second time, the getchar() first recieves the '\n' left in the first line and scanf reads the "p" properly.
Remove the getchar() and your code would work fine.

Comment: I've edited my post.. and even with cChoose[2] the program only recognizes the "p" letter on second try..

Comment: why have you placed a getchar() before scanf statement?

Comment: as i learned, this prevents the program from get the ENTER KEY.. that way the program will just get the KEY that is pressed... that isn't right?

Comment: No, that is wrong. If you would have been using getchar() to recieve your input "p" as a character then you might would have required that. But with string comparision as you are doing, you dont need it.

Comment: ok.. now, i have that code: [link](www.wikarus.com.br/code.txt)[/link]

without the getchar... however, if i choose any letter but "p" the program starts an infinite loop... without give-me the chance to type other letter again, even with the scanf there...

why that happens? :(

Comment: Use scanf("%1s[^\n]", cChoose) instead of scanf("%1[^\n]", cChoose).

Answer (score 3):

```
int cChoose;
...
    cChoose = getchar();
} while( cChoose != 'p' && cChoose != EOF );
```

You seem to like using scanf, probably because it handles whitespace for you.  Instead, try:

```
int cChoose;
...
    do cChoose = getchar(); while( isspace( cChoose ));
} while( cChoose != 'p' && cChoose != EOF );
```

(Although that's a strange way to write it and is really just another example of using do/while.  It would normally be written:

```
int cChoose;
...
    while( isspace( cChoose = getchar()))
        ;
} while( cChoose != 'p' && cChoose != EOF );
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfect... but... why say cChoose are INT? i don't understand that

Comment: if getchar fails for some reason, it returns an out of band value (-1).  Otherwise it returns a value between 0 and 255 inclusive.

Answer (score 1):

The method you should use to compare two strings in C is `strcmp` as in

```
while ( strcmp( cChoose, "p" ) )
```

`strcmp` returns 0 (false) if the strings are identical, or a non-zero value if they differ.

Your statement

```
while ( cChoose != "p" )
```

compares the locations of two pointers in memory, one of which, `cChoose` points to data on the stack and `"p"` which points to static data. They will never be equal.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **strcmp** instead of "**!=**" check the content of the cChoose whether equal "p" or not.

cChoose is a pointer which points to the start position of the array in memory. It is definitely not equal to the "p" start position in memory, so you get the infinite loop in your program.